# How to access data in ObservableCollection from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This may be a long shot but what I've done is create a model representing a table in my database.

```
public partial class users
{
    public int id { get; set }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string gender { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

And my database looks like this with the below values
Titles:

> > ### id | firstName | surName | gender | age

Data

> > 1 | John | Smith | Male | 32
> >
> > 2 | Brad | Reed | Male | 28
> >
> > 3 | Titus | Ward | Male | 25
> >
> > 4 | Seth | Shaw | Male | 26

So since I'm trying to use the mvvm pattern, I have a view model. This view model has an observable collection represeting the above model declared. It also has five properties, each respectively representing a field in the Table, which is where the problem comes in;

```
public class ViewModel
{
    #region ObservableCollection

    private ObservableCollection<users> _user;
    public ObservableCollection<users> User
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set
        { if (_user != value)
                value = _user;
          OnPropertyChanged("User"); }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    private string _id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { if (value != _id)
                _id= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }

    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set { if (value != _firstName)
                _firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    private string _surName;
    public string SurName
    {
        get { return _surName; }
        set { if (value != _surName)
                _surName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SurName");
        }
    }

    private string _gender;
    public string Gender
    {
        get { return _gender; }
        set { if (value != _gender )
                _gender = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
        }
    }

    private string _age;
    public string Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { if (value != _age )
                _age = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Age");
        }
    }
```

So normally if you wanted to convey these details in a UserControl you'd create a DataGrid, bind it's ItemSource to the ObservableCollection ('User' in my case) and then bind its columns to the properties inside the model. That would work fine.

However what I need is for the properties inside my ViewModel to contain the selected record and bind my UI Elements (such as textboxes) to the view model's properties instead. This is because I need the VM to do quite a bit of querying based on which person is selected at the time. For instance, saving the current user to another table entirely.

Like I said. It's a long shot. Can this be done? I guess my logic of thinking right now is if the view can access this data then why wouldn't the ViewModel.

Comment: You need a `SelectedItem` property which you bind the currently selected data object to, then the properties in the VM can access it like any other property or method. But you also don't even need those individual properties - the view can bind to the properties directly on the selected item via your SelectedItem property.

Comment: *normally if you wanted to convey these details in a UserControl you'd create a DataGrid*... that's a fairly broad statement when using WPF. I rarely if ever use a `DataGrid`... think outside the box... this is WPF.

Comment: @slugster looking that up. Thanks, that was helpful... Unlike some other moderators I know...

Comment: .... and I take that back...

Comment: Sheridan has given a [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26995630/109702) (I didn't have time previously), check the comment I left underneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to read through the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN first... you need to learn about data binding. A typical set up would look like this:

Your view model:

```
public ObservableCollection<User> Users
{
    get { return users; }
    set { users = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Users"); }
}

public User SelectedUser
{
    get { return user; }
    set { user = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedUser"); }
}
```

Your view:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}" />
```

Now when the application user changes the selected `User` in the `ListBox`, the `SelectedUser` property will be updated to reflect that. So when they click on a Save `Button`, you could potentially do something like this:

```
DataProvider.SaveUser(SelectedUser);
```

Comment: Then your textboxes will have a binding that looks something like `<TextBox Name="AgeTextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedUser.Age}" />`

Comment: Okay this works like a charm. Much grutitude, and yes. I did take your advise on the overview.