# Object reference wasnt set to object instance | bind column width from one dategrid to a second one

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, width, bind

id like to bind the width of a datagridcolumn to another datagridcolumn to synchronize them.

I use a MVVM pattern and I implement a observercollection in my viewmodel

```
 public ObservableCollection<Team_sum> TeamSum
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<Team_sum> col_teamsum = new ObservableCollection<Team_sum>();
            col_teamsum.Add(new Team_sum());
            return col_teamsum;    

        }
    }
```

these collection were bind to a datagrid

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn
                Width="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=Nr},   Path=ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            </DataGridTextColumn>
```

but i got the folowing error
**Object reference wasnt set to object instance**

I get the width value from a second datagrid.

```
 <DataGridTextColumn
                Header="Nr"
                Binding="{Binding Row_number}"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                x:Name="Nr"/>
```

Comment: I find no other solution in this forum

Comment: You're returning a freshly allocated `ObservableCollection<Team_sum>` *each time* the property is accessed.  Instead you need to retain a persistent ObservableCollection inside your view model as shown e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26995630).  If you don't, external bindings will be lost.  I don't know if this is causing your null reference exception however.

Comment: Same advice was given in comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48621069/c-sharp-xaml-object-not-set-to-a-object-instance-binding-width-from-a-datagr